# Crouching issues in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've created crouching in Unity 2D game, everything goes well except when there is something above the character after exiting crouching, what it does is that it returns to idle animation and decreases Y-axis position, I know that is normal but how can I keep the character crouched when there is something above him or when I hold the ctrl button? Check the script down below if necessary. Thanks!

```c#
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private float h = 0.0f;
    public float Speed, Jump;
    private bool canJump;
    private Animator anim;
    private BoxCollider2D bc2d;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        bc2d = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(h));
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * h * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (h != 0.0f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(h, transform.localScale.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump == true)
        {
            rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, Jump));
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            bc2d.enabled = false;
            Speed = Speed / 2;
            anim.SetBool("Crouch", true);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            bc2d.enabled = true;
            Speed = Speed * 2;
            anim.SetBool("Crouch", false);
        }









    }




    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "Ground")
        {
            canJump = true;
            anim.SetBool("Jump", false);
        }

    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.name == "Ground")
        {
            canJump = false;
            anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In its current form, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Are you asking how to detect if there's an obstacle above? If you already have code for that, try using it and if you can't get something to work with it, show us what you tried.

Comment: I’ve created trigger in the area where the character has to crouch in order to pass, and wrote stuff in trigger collision function but it still stayed crouched after passing that area despite not holding the key.

Comment: Do you have a `bool` or a method that shows whether the character is currently overlapping such an area? If you do, can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56175322/edit) and include it please?

Comment: Brackeys on Youtube as a nice [video on 2D Movement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwcT-Dch0bA) including crouching if you are interested in checking out his solution.

Comment: @TimHunter That doesn’t solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [RaycastHit2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html). Basically before "standing" cast a ray Vector2.up from the character and if it hits, check to make sure there's enough room to stand. Something like:

```
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;   
private Transform t;
private float h = 0.0f;
public float Speed, Jump;
private bool canJump;
private Animator anim;
private BoxCollider2D bc2d;

// Variable to check if character is attempting to stand
private bool tryingToStand = false;
// Keep crouching state
private bool isCrouching = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    bc2d = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    t = GetComponent<Transform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(h));
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * h * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (h != 0.0f)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(h, transform.localScale.y);
    }
    // Make sure we can jump and we're not crouching before jumping
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump == true && !isCrouching)
    {
        rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, Jump));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        bc2d.enabled = false;
        anim.SetBool("Crouch", true);
        // Make sure we haven't already halved the speed
        if (!tryingToStand)
        {
            Speed = Speed / 2;
        }
        // Set tryingToStand to false in case player holds ctrl before character has stood up
        tryingToStand = false;
        // Set crouching state to true
        isCrouching = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        tryingToStand = true;            
    }

    if (tryingToStand && CanStand())
    {
        tryingToStand = false;
        // Set crouching state to false;
        isCrouching = false;
        bc2d.enabled = true;
        Speed = Speed * 2;
        anim.SetBool("Crouch", false);
    }
}

bool CanStand()
{        
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(t.position, Vector2.up);
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        // Check the distance to make sure the character has clearance, you'll have to change the 1.0f to what makes sense in your situation.
        if (hit.distance <= 1.0f)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;    
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.name == "Ground")
    {
        canJump = true;
        anim.SetBool("Jump", false);
    }    
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.name == "Ground")
    {
        canJump = false;
        anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I write this in my script? I've shown full script. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer. That should work for you, if not let me know.

Comment: Thanks. but when I get out of that area it still stays crouched, I want it to automatically uncrouch when passing that area, if not holding ctrl.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. CanStand() was returning false if no collider was detected above player. I updated the code. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: I've noticed the speed issues, can you please look over the script?

Comment: Sure, what kind of speed issues? Performance or character movement?

Comment: Sometimes speed becomes halfed after passing that area, I've noticed that it occurs when uncrouching when in the area and then passing with crouching.

Comment: It would keep halving the speed if you press the ctrl key multiple times without being able to stand. I updated the answer to add a check to make sure it only gets halved once.

Comment: That's cool, thanks for everything, and the last issues is jumping, how can I set canJump to false when entering the area? I've tried to write it in if statement (tryingToStand && CanStand()) but it doesn't work.

Comment: You could add an `isCrouching` variable to hold the crouching state and check that before jumping. I've updated the answer.